# How to include home path in template

Tags: css, path

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically call an ExpressionEngine home path. For instance, in Wordpress they use `<?php echo home_url(); ?>`, is there an equivalent for ExpressionEngine? I am wanting to link to my stylesheets without putting the absolute static path into the href.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `{site_url}` which will return the site's homepage url such as http://www.mysite.com

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: or {homepage} or {path='site_index'}